# SQL (mysql) query explanation for multiple row update using group by sub query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables, countries and users

`users`

| id | country_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 |

`countries`

| id | monthly_count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 |

I want to update the monthly_count column in countries table by counting rows in users table grouped by country_id **in a single update query**. So after updating the countries table will look like this:

`countries`

| id | monthly_count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 |

The query I ended up with is:

```
UPDATE countries c 
SET c.monthly_count = (
    SELECT COUNT(u.country_id) FROM users u 
    WHERE u.country_id = c.id 
    GROUP BY u.country_id
);
```

The query is working as expected. It is updating the monthly_count column of every row in the countries table with corresponding correct count values for each country_id group from users table.

However, I am not sure how the query is working. The main question I have is, how the result of subquery is assigned to the correct row? Is the subquery executed one time and returning all the group by count values for each country_id at once or, is the sub query being executed each time for every row in countries table?

Answer (score 2):

I would write this an update join:

```sql
UPDATE countries c
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT country_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM users
    GROUP BY country_id
) u
     ON u.country_id = c.id
SET c.monthly_count = u.cnt;
```

That being said, the monthly counts are *aggregate* data, and you might want to consider *not* doing this update or storing this data.  So, I am happy with the following query or view:

```sql
SELECT c.id, COUNT(u.cnt) AS monthly_count
FROM countries c
LEFT JOIN users u
    ON u.country_id = c.id
GROUP BY c.id;
```

Comment: *`COALESCE(COUNT(u.cnt), 0) AS monthly_count`* - the usage of COALESCE() makes no sense, COUNT() cannot return NULL.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The query you wrote is much better than the one I was using but still it doesn't answer how the update query in question is assigning new values to each row.
I think what I am looking for is an explanation of how update query works so if you could point me to any documentation/source code will be much appreciated.